# Open Jquery modal dialog on click event

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

The below code works fine for only the first click event. However for any subsequent click nothing happens.
I tested this on firefox, ie7 but still the same. Am I missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#dialog').dialog();
    $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>    
</head><body>
   <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style="display:none"> Some text</div>  
   <p id="dialog_link">Open Dialog</p>  
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#dialog').dialog(); 
    $('#dialog_link').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

there is a open arg in the last part

Comment: Sorry no luck :(

I put an alert("kkh"); before $('#dialog').dialog();
and it comes fine but no window yet.

Comment: check your references on the clientside, i use firebug to check that there are no 404s

Comment: point @user20358 just removed the first $('#dialog').dialog();

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
    $(function() {

$('#clickMe').click(function(event) {
    var mytext = $('#myText').val();


    $('<div id="dialog">'+mytext+'</div>').appendTo('body');        
    event.preventDefault();

        $("#dialog").dialog({                   
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").remove();
                }
            });
    }); //close click
});
```

And in HTML

```
<h3 id="clickMe">Open dialog</h3>
<textarea cols="0" rows="0" id="myText" style="display:none">Some hidden text display none</textarea>
```

Comment: Great solution - I liked this!

Comment: Yeah, the .remove() function is the answer to my woes.  When I was calling .close() it was causing the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function() {

$('#clickMe').click(function(event) {
    var mytext = $('#myText').val();

    $('<div id="dialog">'+mytext+'</div>').appendTo('body');        
    event.preventDefault();

        $("#dialog").dialog({                   
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            close: function(event, ui) {
                $("#dialog").hide();
                }
            });
    }); //close click
});
```

Better to use .hide() instead of .remove(). With .remove() it returns undefined if you have pressed the link once, then close the modal and if you press the modal link again, it returns undefined with .remove.

With .hide() it doesnt and it works like a breeze. Ty for the snippet in the first hand!

Comment: If you just hide it then the #dialog div will be appended again and again

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put some page in the dialog then you can use these

```
function Popup()
{
 $("#pop").load('login.html').dialog({
 height: 625,
 width: 600,
 modal:true,
 close: function(event,ui){
     $("pop").dialog('destroy');

        }
 }); 

}
```

HTML:

```
<Div id="pop"  style="display:none;">

</Div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be helpful... :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buutonId').on('click', function() {
        $('#modalId').modal('open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before your dialog line.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
```

This method worked for me.  It seems that the "close" command messes up the dialog opening again with only the .dialog() .

Using your code as an example, it would go in like this (note that you may need to add more to your code for it to make sense):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#dialog').dialog();
    $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );        
$('#dialog').dialog();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>    
</head><body>
   <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style="display:none"> Some text</div>  
   <p id="dialog_link">Open Dialog</p>  
</body></html>
```