# Open pop up dialog in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to open a pop up window, doing the basic thing to start with, but instead is showing me the dialog when the page loads, plus the button doesn't trigger anything.

```
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
<script>
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
</script>
```

This are my imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I am doing wrong or forgetting to import?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Jquery modal dialog on click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964482/open-jquery-modal-dialog-on-click-event)

Comment: wrap the contents of your script tag in `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: Also with wrapping my code after re-organizing the libraries, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

`dialog` isn't built into jQuery - it is part of jQuery UI which is an extension of jQuery - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/.

Also it looks like you are importing 3 different versions of the core jQuery code, which will probably cause issues.

So this is probably what you are looking for (after downloading jQuery UI to your scripts folder):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json.debug.js"></script>
```

And then open it using the [`open()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open) method:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).open();
});
```

Comment: So I've organized my imports like you suggested, and sorry for not answering back, but I had to clean up after eliminating some libraries. So still this way doesn't fire! JQuery UI I've added only the core and no widget fyi.